# How to stop HTML text in textarea to be interpreted as code

Tags: php, html, textarea

I have a textarea that users can edit. After the edit I save the text in a PHP variable $bio. When I want to display it I do this:

```
    <?php 
    $bio = nl2br($bio);
    echo $bio;
    ?>
```

But if a user for example types an HTML command like "strong" in their text my site will actually output the text as bold. Which is nothing I want.

How can I print/echo the $bio on the screen just as text and not as HTML code?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `echo $bio;` with `echo htmlspecialchars($bio);`

http://php.net/htmlspecialchars

Answer (score 0):

When you output text to the html / the browser and you want to make sure that the output does not break the html, you should always use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

In your case you do want to show the `<br>` tags, so you should do that before you add them:

```
$bio = nl2br(htmlspecialchars($bio));
```

You can also use `strip_tags()` to get rid of the html tags altogether, but you would still need to use `htmlspecialchars()` so that for example a `<` character will not break your html.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [htmlentites()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title></title>
</head>

<body>

<form method="POST" action="">
    <p><textarea rows="8" name="bio" cols="40"></textarea></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
</form>
<p>Result:</p>
<?php echo isset($_POST['bio']) ? htmlentities($_POST['bio']) : null; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

So like:

[image: example]